# Outlook Message Size With Embedded Images

Tags: image, outlook, size

When I "insert" an image into an Outlook e-mail, the size of the e-mail tends to get very large.  For example, if the inserted image is 150kb the sent message is often 5mb (in this case there is only a line or two of text and the image).  If I attach the file the e-mail size is what I'd expect.  Can anyone explain why this is happening, and more importantly how I can insert a picture and keep the e-mail size to what it should be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that in the RTF format? In case case you get an embedded OLE object, which contains the original data as well as the bitmap used to render the contents of the OLE object inline without initializing the app that created the OLE object (plus a few other things, like an icon, size information, etc.).

That being said, this is not a programming question.

Comment: Yes, it is in Rich Text Format.  I'm not sure what the "not programming question" reference is all about, but I appreciate the answer!  I'll try sending the e-mail in another format.